# Insert character at the beginning of specific lines

Tags: text-processing, sed

Let's say I have file:

```
% This is first line
% This is second line

This is content

% This is the end
```

How can I insert a `%` character at the beginning of every line which already starts with `%`?

Result:

```
%% This is first line
%% This is second line

This is content

%% This is the end
```

Comment: this was tagged with [bash] and [sed], so I assume you're not limited to using just plain Bash by itself..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `sed`

```
sed 's/^%/%%/' infile
```

replace beginning `%` with `%%` for the lines if starts with. 
The `^` is an anchor which points to the beginning of the line; there is `$` which points to the end of line. 
to have change write to file in-place, use `-i` option of *sed*.

There is another way which will do replace faster than above (if your file is huge enough you will notice the difference)

```
sed '/^%/ s/^/%/' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be obtained with `sed` and `awk` (though there are other ways as well)

1. Using `sed`:
   `sed -i 's/^%/%&/' <your_file>`
2. Using `awk`:
   `awk '/^%/ { $0 = "%" $0 } 1' <your_file>`